# test class fails system.assert but manual upload performs as expected

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, class

I don't understand why when i upload the two invoices in my test class through the data wizard they perform as expected based on the triggers I've written. but when i run this test class it fails due to the 2nd system.assert 'not first invoice not correctly marked as false'.

I've tested multiple uploads through the data wizard and they all worked.

Is there something special about how the test class tests that would cause the discrepancy?

Here is the test class:

```
@isTest
public class testFirstInvoice {
static testMethod void testInvoice() {

Account ab = new Account();
ab.LastName = 'bob';
insert ab;

Recurly_Plan__c p = new Recurly_Plan__c();
p.Name = 'Plan B';
insert p;

Recurly_Subscription__c rs = new Recurly_Subscription__c();
rs.Name = 'recurly subscription';
rs.Account__c = ab.Id;
rs.Recurly_Plan__c = p.Id;
insert rs;


Recurly_Invoice__c a = new Recurly_Invoice__c();
a.Closed_at__c = datetime.now();
a.Account__c = ab.Id;
a.Subscription__c = rs.Id;
a.Invoice_uuid__c = 'sfdafsfaf';
a.Invoice_Number__c = 'asfaskjfa';
a.Total_in_cents__c = 20;
a.Status__c = 'Collected';
insert a;

Recurly_Invoice__c b = new Recurly_Invoice__c();
b.Account__c = ab.Id;
b.Subscription__c = rs.Id;
b.Invoice_uuid__c = 'sfdafasfassfaf';
b.Invoice_Number__c = 'asfasfaskjfa';
b.Total_in_cents__c = 20;
b.Status__c = 'Open';
insert b;

System.assert(a.First_Invoice_del__c = true, 'first invoice not correctly marked true');
System.assert(b.First_Invoice_del__c = false, 'not first invoice not correctly marked false');

}}
```

Public Class used in FirstInvoiceAfter trigger:

```
//public class to avoid recursion in trigger 
public Class checkRecursive{
private static boolean run = true;
public static boolean runOnce(){
if(run){
 run=false;
 return true;
}else{
    return run;
}
}
}
```

FirstInvoiceAfter Trigger:

```
trigger FirstInvoiceAfter on Recurly_Invoice__c (after insert, after update) {
if(checkRecursive.runOnce()) {

Set<Id> parentAccountsId = new Set<Id>();
for (Recurly_Invoice__c startInvoices : Trigger.new) {
    parentAccountsId.add(startInvoices.Account__c);
 }

list<Recurly_Invoice__c> siblingInvoices = [SELECT Id
                                            FROM Recurly_Invoice__c
                                            WHERE Account__c IN : parentAccountsId];

List<Recurly_Invoice__c> invoicesToUpdate = new List<Recurly_Invoice__c>{};

for (Recurly_Invoice__c invoice : siblingInvoices) {
        invoice.First_Invoice_del__c = false;
        invoicesToUpdate.add(invoice);
        } 
update invoicesToUpdate;
}}
```

FirstInvoiceBefore Trigger:

```
trigger FirstInvoiceBefore on Recurly_Invoice__c (before insert, before update) {
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Recurly_Invoice__c record : trigger.new) 
 accountIds.add(record.Account__c);

Map<Id, Datetime> earliestCloseDates = new Map<Id, Datetime>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
SELECT Account__c, MIN(Closed_At__c) earliestClose FROM Recurly_Invoice__c
WHERE Account__c IN :accountIds AND Status__c = 'Collected'
GROUP BY Account__c
])
earliestCloseDates.put(
    (Id)aggregate.get('Account__c'),
    (Datetime)aggregate.get('earliestClose')
);

for (Recurly_Invoice__c record : trigger.new)
{
if (record.Closed_At__c == earliestCloseDates.get(record.Account__c))
    record.First_Invoice_del__c = true;
}}
```

EDIT***

Thank you Thomas and cropredy for the suggestions. I tried both of them and i'm still seeing the error. Here is what my test class looks like after your suggested edits..

```
@isTest
public class testFirstInvoice {
static testMethod void testInvoice() {

Account ab = new Account();
ab.LastName = 'bob';
insert ab;

Recurly_Plan__c p = new Recurly_Plan__c();
p.Name = 'Plan B';
insert p;

Recurly_Subscription__c rs = new Recurly_Subscription__c();
rs.Name = 'recurly subscription';
rs.Account__c = ab.Id;
rs.Recurly_Plan__c = p.Id;
insert rs;

List<Recurly_Invoice__c> invoicesToUpdate = new List<Recurly_Invoice__c>{};



Recurly_Invoice__c a = new Recurly_Invoice__c();
a.Closed_at__c = datetime.now();
a.Account__c = ab.Id;
a.Subscription__c = rs.Id;
a.Invoice_uuid__c = 'sfdafsfaf';
a.Invoice_Number__c = 'asfaskjfa';
a.Total_in_cents__c = 20;
a.Status__c = 'Collected';
invoicesToUpdate.add(a);

Recurly_Invoice__c b = new Recurly_Invoice__c();
b.Account__c = ab.Id;
b.Subscription__c = rs.Id;
b.Invoice_uuid__c = 'sfdafasfassfaf';
b.Invoice_Number__c = 'asfasfaskjfa';
b.Total_in_cents__c = 20;
b.Status__c = 'Open';
invoicesToUpdate.add(b);

insert invoicesToUpdate;

Recurly_Invoice__c x = [SELECT Id, First_Invoice_del__c FROM Recurly_Invoice__c WHERE Invoice_Number__c = 'asfaskjfa'] ;
Recurly_Invoice__c y = [SELECT Id, First_Invoice_del__c FROM Recurly_Invoice__c WHERE Invoice_Number__c = 'asfasfaskjfa'] ;

System.assert(x.First_Invoice_del__c = true, 'first invoice not correctly marked true');
System.assert(y.First_Invoice_del__c = false, 'not first invoice not correctly marked false');

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the Data Import Wizard works differently than your test class has to do with transactional context

In the data wizard, multiple records are sent to the trigger in a batch; if more than 200 records in the input, then multiple transactions, each of size 200.  Between each transaction, all static variables are reset (i.e. your trigger recursion variables)

In your test class, you insert Recurly_Invoices in two separate DMLs which means the trigger gets invoked twice. The recursion variable is never reset back to its null state

You need a recursion reset method between each insert (or insert both test records in one DML

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's an answer for this somewhere here on SFSE, but I'm not easily finding it.

You need to query your records back out of the database between your insert and your assert in order to get them in their post- trigger state. Eg:

```
a = [SELECT Id, First_Invoice_del__c FROM Recurly_Invoice__c WHERE Invoice_Number__c = "asfaskjfk"] ;
b = [SELECT Id, First_Invoice_del__c FROM Recurly_Invoice__c WHERE Invoice_Number__c = "asfasfaskjfk"] ;
```